# Regular expression to match the last occurrence in substring

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a text like this

```
words words words tag a words words tag a words tag b words time words words tag c words time
```

I dont know what a,b and c are. What I want to capture is "`tag b words time`", `tag c words time`" and any other like it. So my attempted regexp was `tag[\w ]+?time`. But that matches

```
tag a words words tag a words tag b words time
```

How do I capture the last occurrence of tag? I am using matlab so if there is a non regexp solution to this that would be great too.

Comment: https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#responsive_offcanvas for without regex.

Comment: @LonelyPlanet you cannot do that here as I dont know what a/b/c are, as I mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
tag\s*[\w]\s*[\w]+\s*time
```

Comment: I tried it on regex101.com and that one does not match anything.

Comment: Wow! that works. Needed little modification when I applied it to the real problem but this is a good general solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/tag [a-z]{4} [\w]+ time$/
```

Here is a working example (in javascript, however if you use PCRE it should work in matlab to).

```js
s1 = "words words words tag a words words tag a words tag b words time words words tag cccc words time"
re = /tag [a-z]{4} [\w]+ time$/
console.log(s1.match(re))
```

Comment: I thought it would be clear that "words" is just a dummy. Also this will only capture the last occurrence in the whole string.

Comment: so both c and words are dummy? what could go there? how do you define these chars/words?

Comment: Define these? I don't quite know what you are asking. They are just words in a text file.

Comment: char limit? which chars? exactly two words? any number of words?

Comment: `b` and `c` are not words there are **exactly** 1 char (for example)

Comment: Oh ok. words can be literally anything. Actually it can also be non standard chars. Tags b and c are of 4 characters, all small case.